# Symfony 4 : FMElfinderBundle upload image Blank page

Tags: symfony

I use FMElfinderBundle to upload image in my blog.
But, when I want to "Browse server" in order to upload image, I get a blank page with this errors:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMnq5.png)

```
#config/packages/fm_elfinder.yaml

fm_elfinder:
assets_path: "/public/uploads/images/post_img" # Le dossier configuré dans composer.json
instances:
    ckeditor:
        locale:           "%locale%"
        editor:           "ckeditor"
        fullscreen:       false
        include_assets:   true
        connector:
            debug:        false
            roots:
                uploads:
                    driver:           "LocalFileSystem"
                    path:             "/public/uploads/images/post_img"
                    upload_allow:     ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'application/zip', 'audio/mpeg', 'text/csv', 'video/mp4', 'video/webm', 'application/pdf']
                    upload_deny:      ['all']
                    upload_max_size:  "8M"
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: It seems there was some kind of server error. Could you also post the content of `var/log/dev.log`?

Comment: A lot of things are in dev.log. What kind of errors are interested? All the files not found throw a `request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException` exception

Comment: That definitely is the problem you are having. Those IllegalArgumentExceptions are turned into a 500 error and that is why it's not working. You should try opening the URL directly to see a proper error page and a stack trace. That could help identifying the issue. If you don't know which URL, you can just use the network tab in your browser's developer tools. There you should see the same files with the 500 status code and with a right click you can open the URL.

Comment: Ok, I have a `No route found for "GET /public/uploads/images/post_img/elfinder/dist/css/theme.css"` error. Which makes sens. Maybe I have to change the place of all the required files?

Comment: That is odd. No route found, should be a 404 error, not 500. But let's start there. Can you maybe add your twig template headers, where you have the stylesheets? How did you add those required files? It looks like you are supposed to copy the files to `web/assets` or use some composer plugin-mechanism for it: https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle#step-1-installation

Comment: An example: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vendor/css/demo.css" />`. Also I changed the place files and put it into `web/assets`...but always 500

Comment: `web/` references the document root. You have to ignore it from the url, so it should probably be `/assets/...`. Are you sure those missing assets cause a 500 error? As I previously mentioned those files should throw a 404. A 500 error indicates some issue in the php code, like the `InvalidArgumentException` above. You should probably trace this error first.